# how to get different numbers in Math.random java

Tags: java

Got a challenge from my teacher.
This is the problem:

```java
int x = (int) (Math.random() * 37 + 1);
int y = (int) (Math.random() * 37 + 1);
System.out.println( x + " " y);
```

I was asked to make that x won't be equal to y without using conditions/for/while/etc/functions. Thanks.

Comment: You must have wandered into the Java class accidentally.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are two completely separate languages.

Comment: Your question title says "javascript", but you tag with "java". Not at all the same languages. So, which one is it?

Comment: Pick an x, add something to it to get y.  As long as the something isn't 0 they won't be the same.

Comment: Beyond that: **you** got that challenge from your teacher. So, what are your thoughts?

Comment: I thought the same like azurefog but I dont think it will be counted as an answer
I started java about 2 weeks ago,  trying my best and its night in my timezone so i dont want to ask my teacher.

Comment: Clearly you need to use some math operations.   XOR might be useful here.

Comment: Do `x` and `y` have to be within a certain range? As in, do they both have to be greater than 0 and less than 37?

Comment: You can just do `x = y + 1` after the `Random` calls, it didn't say you couldn't change them!

Comment: *"without using conditions/for/while/ **etc** /functions"* - So... What can you use?  "etc" covers a lot of ground.  It's not really clear to me what's being asked.  And if that's the exact information given to you by your instructor, that would explain why it's also not really clear to you.

Comment: I need to generate two random numbers that are not the same without using conditions or functions or doing x = y + 1.

Comment: As I said , its a challenge.
he just told us that if we can generate two different numbers without functions/conditions we might get bonus points..
Only 3 weeks in class moved from chemistry and trying my best

Answer (score 0):

good that you started with java :-) As some operations are are prohibited, I'd expect this question to be about the sign of you numbers. As x and y are both positive and multiplication with -1 of y (or x but not both) would do the trick.

```java
Math.random()
```

is always positive. So both numbers would usually be positive. As you added one to the random value they are both also not zero. By changing the sign of one of the variables, they would always differ.

```java
int x = (int) (Math.random() * 37 + 1);
int y = (int) (Math.random() * 37 + 1);
System.out.println(x + " " + (y*-1));
```

Comment: Hi :)
Its just like lottery(At least in my country)
Once you get a number you cant get it again.
the range of numbers is 1-37 and *positive*